# Use Synaptics Touchpad Scroll in Mac OS X 10.9 VMware Guest

Tags: macos, vmware-workstation, synaptics-touchpad

I have a multi touchpad it is working perfect in windows 8.1 and I have Mac OS X 10.9 in vmware but the Mac gestures don't work I installed the latest vmware tool and they are not working. Is there any driver I should install ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the program called "twofingerscroll"

I have used it and it works fine for me.

> This project aims at providing a tool for Windows platform adding some useful two finger gestures to Synaptics TouchPads. These TouchPads can be found in many todays laptops and many of them support multiple finger gestures.
>
> > Currently supported gestures:
> >
> > - Two finger scrolling - scroll vertically by sliding two fingers anywhere on the TouchPad
> > - Two finger tapping - tap with two fingers to simulate a selected mouse button

Download it [here](https://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/)

Comment: Please at least summarize the link, it can go stale and your answer becomes useless.